# why my SharedViewModel is Executing first?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)

        val recyclerView = view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity())
        
        noDataTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.no_data_textView)
        noDataImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.no_data_imageView)
        
        mToDoViewModel.getAllData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { data ->
            adapter.setData(data)
            mSharedViewModel.checkIfDatabaseEmpty(data)
        })
        
        floatingActionButton = view.findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.floatingActionButton)
        listLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.listLayout)
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_addFragment)
        }
        //set menu
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        
        mSharedViewModel.emptyDatabase.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { data ->
            showEmptyDatabaseViews(data)
        })

        return view
    }
```

I have a visibility system going on where if the database is empty then the image is shown.
but when I run the code first image shows up then the data shows up then I debugged it and seen that ***mSharedViewModel.emptyDatabase.observe()*** function is running first? what is the main issue here,

ps, I am using suspended fun to load the data

Edit 1:
my default visibility is invisible

```
<ImageView>
.
.
android:visibility="invisible"
```

this is my ShareViewModel Class Which will check the database empty or not

```
class SharedViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val emptyDatabase: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(true)

    fun checkIfDatabaseEmpty(toDoData: List<ToDoData>){
        emptyDatabase.value=toDoData.isEmpty()
    }
```

and this my ViewModel

```
class ToDoViewModel(application: Application):AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val toDoDao= ToDoDatabase.getDatabase(application).ToDoDao()
    private val repository:ToDoRepository

    val getAllData: LiveData<List<ToDoData>>

init {
        repository=ToDoRepository(toDoDao)
        getAllData=repository.getAllData
    }
```

Comment: Please describe both your expectations and results more clearly. It's not clear from your current description. And we probably need to see how your LiveData's are defined and values posted to them to be able to tell you what behavior they should have.

Comment: The default visibility of the view is not `GONE` so it is visible when the layout is inflated and then when the observer receives an emission it will hide it.

Comment: i have edited and add more details for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation:
I have a visibility system going on where if the database is empty then the image is shown.

According to your code:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

The default visibility is `invisible` okay but check the view model code

```
val emptyDatabase: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(true)
```

You set the value to `true`. So when any `observer` start `observing` the changes, the `default value` will be passed to the `observer`, so logically your code is `OK`, database is `empty` and image view is `visible`.

So, you should set `false` as the `default value`.

Comment: thanks. but i am curious it's there any order code that got executed, I debugged this issue and first mSharedViewModel is running despite being lower in code line

Comment: Well your code is executed sequentially but observer callback depends on the scenario.

Comment: thanks that will give me good night sleep

Comment: Your shared `viewmodel` is already instantiated, so does the `LiveData` too. But `fragment` viewmodel will be instantiated.